# Akka Actor get time left on Timer

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I'm using Java, but a Scala solution will be fine (I will try to translate it).

I have an actor that implements `AbstractActorWithTimers`. When the actor is created a timer with is life span is started (something like 60 seconds):

```java
    private void setLifeSpanTimer(){
        getTimers().startSingleTimer("lifespan", PoisonPill.getInstance(), this.lifeSpan);
    }
```

I give a name to this timer: `lifespan`. Now, when I receive a specific message I would like to give back the time left on this timer.

How can I get the time left on this specific timer?

I found only a way to check if the timer is active:

```java
        getTimers().isTimerActive("lifespan");
```

Comment: I didnt find any useful method on the class https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/actor/AbstractActorWithTimers.html that offers this functionality to you and I was thinking maybe you can start a timer on the `Actor#preStart()` method. have you thought about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by initiating the Actor with the timestamp of the actor creation. Then when receiving a specific message you would use this timestamp to get the time left. I don't think there is an API that allows asking timers about their internal state.